# Display result from original search term before the result of its synonyms

Tags: solr

I am stuck during synonym implementation in solr. Normal Multi-Term is working fine, but our client is demanding that the result for Searched Term should appear at top and then results for its synonyms should appear. I haven't came across any way yet so I am posting this here. Any help would be very appreciable. Also, boosting is applied to search fields and operators like "AND" "OR" are used in query. Following is the example with query:
Synonyms Configured: "integrated campaign,campaign framework"

Search Term 1: "integrated campaign"
Search Result 1: Records with integrated campaign appear first while records with campaign framework appears second.

Search Term 2: "campaign framework"
Search Result 2: Here again Records with integrated campaign appear first while records with campaign framework appears second.

Expected outcome:
Search Result 1: Records with integrated campaign appear first while records with campaign framework appears second.

Search Result 2: Records with campaign framework appear first while records with integrated campaign appears second.

I have also tried Nolan's plugin for phrase queries during multi-word synonyms
https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms

Following is my solr query:

q=has_presentation_b:(True)+AND+(-exclude_from_search_b:(True))+AND+(title_t:(%22integrated+campaign%22))+OR+(promotional_keywords_t:(%22integrated+campaign%22))+OR+(promotional_description_t:(%22integrated+campaign%22))+OR+(abstract_t:(%22integrated+campaign%22))+OR+(body_t:(%22integrated+campaign%22))

Solr Version: 6.3.0

Thanks,
Lalit Joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second field with the same processing chain, but without synonym expansion. Boost this field appropriately (by using `field_name:query^<value>` or supplying the field in `qf`) when searching, so that any hits in that field are worth more than hits in the field that has synonyms expanded.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correct response everytime. :)